# xamarin form next back button fixed bar

Tags: xamarin.forms

I am newbie to Xamarin forms and I have to implement something like bellow.
where in very bottom of the page there is a next button and back button and in the middle of the page having some page indicator where current page is rely.

what my question is I need to change the page content upon click in next and back button ? how do I can start doing something like this ?

[image]

In simple term are there like xamarin form page where it having container to embedded view to that page dynamically.

Comment: wonder why this get down vote.this is a genuine question. I can't explain without an image. that's why I use image wonder why I getting blocking asking genuine question ?

Comment: People expect a bit of coding most of the times, this answer looks similar to the carouselpage of earlier, the only thing you'll need to do is add 2 extra buttons to it and program it to go swap to a other item in the  list of pages.

Comment: Thanks Jordy,I already do it in carouselpage but thing is here swipe control should be disabled where it can't achieve in carouselpage.

Comment: So you want them to only be able to navigate to use those 2 buttons ?

Comment: yes exactly and they can be able to go to previous by clicking the dotted indicate. Its like steps here.

Comment: For the disable you'll need a renderer of the carouselpage where you do a foreach for eveyrgesturerecognizer and where you return false. Than you add 2 buttons to your page and use program code to navigate between the pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148280/discussion-between-prageeth-and-jordy-dieltjens).

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you need Carousel View. Please read  these articles -[article1](https://xamarinhelp.com/carousel-view-xamarin-forms/), [article2](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/carousel-page/), [article3](https://github.com/alexrainman/CarouselView). Choose something that suits you.

Comment: no Fet,Swipe should be disable here instead having next and back button.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use your carousel page that I showed you previous time. You make a renderer for the carousel page where your override all the gestures of that carouselpage ( do this on you viewdidload )

```
foreach (var g in this.View.GestureRecognizers)
            g.ShouldBegin = recognizer => false;
```

Next you just add buttons in XAML code to your carousel page and swap to them programmatically. Here is some extra information on how to do that: http://www.patridgedev.com/2015/03/07/xamarin-forms-switching-tabbedpage-tabs-programmatically/

Note: this is for tabbed page, but should work the same way. (ps you are interested in switching tabs by index, since you want the back and forward button)

Good luck